# How to unstake CPU using multisig and cleos?

Tags: cleos, multisig, unstake

I know that to unstake a simple account I can run the following:

```bash
cleos system undelegatebw FROM RECEIVER unstake_net_quantity unstake_cpu_quantity
```

And I know that to propose a multisig transaction I can do as the documentation says [Link](https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosio.contracts/latest/guides/how-to-sign-a-multisig-transaction-with-eosio.msig):

```bash
cleos multisig propose test '[{"actor": "treasury", "permission": "active"}]' '[{"actor": "treasury", "permission": "active"}]' eosio.token issue '{"to": "tester", "quantity": "1000.0000 SYS", "memo": ""}' -p tester
```

Question, how do I propose a unstake multsig transaction using cleos?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

> cleos multisig propose test '[{"actor": "treasury", "permission":
> "active"}]' '[{"actor": "treasury", "permission": "active"}]'
> eosio.system undelegatebw  '{"from": "tester", "receiver":"tester",
> "unstake_net_quantity": "1000.0000 SYS", "unstake_cpu_quantity":
> "1000.0000 SYS"}' -p tester